# What could cause an overflow exception in System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.CreateInputLanguageChangingEventArgs

Tags: c#, .net, exception, overflow

I have a user that's reporting a very odd Exception that's happening within the .NET framework.

The stack trace from the exception is:

```
System.String StackTrace =   場所 System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguageChangingEventArgs..ctor(InputLanguage inputLanguage, Boolean sysCharSet)
   場所 System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage.CreateInputLanguageChangingEventArgs(Message m)
   場所 System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmInputLangChangeRequest(Message& m)
   場所 System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   場所 BatteryBar.BatteryBar.WndProc(Message& m)
   場所 System.Windows.Forms.Control.ActiveXImpl.System.Windows.Forms.IWindowTarget.OnMessage(Message& m)
   場所 System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   場所 System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I've looked at the InputLanguage class in Reflector and I don't see anything in the constructor of the the InputLanguageChangingEventArgs that could be causing an Overflow exception.

The only thing my application does related to localization is attempt to determine the OS default language and load a translation file into a hashtable if there's a translation available.  The forms do attempt to switch between right-to-left and left-to-right for the appropriate translation, but since this is Japanese, I don't think that would affect it.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am experiencing the same issue with a Japanese user.

Comment: This is a bug in .NET. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32021586/332528

Answer (score 1):

Hmm maybe the japanese symbols are with bigger size in ANCII table than ordinary sizeof(char) - thats only thing that goes in mind.